# Can i Customise Layout.Navigation.Menu with C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, c1-cms

Salam 3ala mani ittaba3a alhoda,

My Layout.Navigation.Menu is written with XSLT, and i would customise it to show a part of them dynamically, for example for anonymous, i hide Compte menu. but i want do that with C# code.
please help me if that is possible, if not how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Install the package "Composite.Navigation.Distributed.Razor" via System | Packages and you get a new function "Composite.Navigation.Distributed" created using C# / Razor. Use version 4 of Composite C1.